# How can I create a slideshow inside a custom dialog?

Tags: android, xml, dialog

I am trying to create a slideshow with some images (already copied into the drawable folder) inside a custom dialog. It's like asking how to treat the dialog as a Java activity/intent, and maybe using a ViewFlipper, animations, or the gallery widget... I've already created the dialog.xml file, and launched my dialog. It works good. I'm familiar with adding images, text, and the usual methods into the dialog, but how could I add in a slideshow of my images?
I'm coding purely with Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You can use frame animation (Animation using multiple image just like gif image)
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Frame